# Binding to DataTemplate dynamically created UserControl Property

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a DataTemplate in App.xaml :

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local2:DirectoryFilesViewModel}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="Auto">
                    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top"><Hyperlink  Style="{StaticResource ButtonHype}"
                    Command="{Binding ClickCommand}"><InlineUIContainer>
                    <Image Source="{Binding FolderImage}"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Stretch="Uniform"
                        RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5"
                        ToolTip="Disc" Margin="7,9,0,0" Height="27" />
                </InlineUIContainer></Hyperlink></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DiscName}" FontSize="2" Margin="8,10,0,0">
                        <TextBlock.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                                        <EventTrigger.Actions>
                                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.7" Storyboard.TargetProperty="FontSize" To="20" />
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </BeginStoryboard>
                                        </EventTrigger.Actions>
                                    </EventTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </TextBlock.Style>
                    </TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding DiscFiles}" >
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <controls:MemberListItem /> // Need to bind to a TextBlock in this Control
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </StackPanel>
/DataTemplate>
```

All is fine except the ListBox UserControl...can't seem to Bind to a TextBlock inside it. Can someone point me in the right direction?

UserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Music.Controls.MemberListItem"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:local2="clr-namespace:MusicMurfer.ViewModels"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         d:DesignHeight="30" d:DesignWidth="300" Height="32" Width="Auto">
<!--<UserControl.DataContext>
    <local2:MemberListViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>-->
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
             Source="{Binding DiscFileImage}" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" Height="15"
            Margin="-2,5,5,5" Stretch="Uniform"  RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5" />

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Width="Auto"  Foreground="White" TextAlignment="Left"
               VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="6" x:Name="FileText" Margin="5,5,5,5"
               Height="Auto" ToolTip="Click to Play" Text="{Binding ThisDoesntWorkYet}">

        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                        <EventTrigger.Actions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.4" Storyboard.TargetProperty="FontSize" To="16" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger.Actions>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

SO complaining mostly code - need details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the actual "MemberListItem" control, you need to set the binding of the TextBox's text property to the data member that will be present on the datacontext of the user control (which is a specific member in the DiscFiles collection).

So if your user control is something like:

```
<UserControl>
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding DiscFileName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</UserControl>
```

Replace "DiscFileName" with the "Name" property on the DiscFile object.  You do not put the text binding on the actual instance of the User Control inside the DataTemplate.

Comment: This will work. Depending on what you need, you might have to also look into DependencyProperties. They might come in handy

Comment: "data member that will be present on the datacontext of the user control"

Comment: "data member that will be present on the datacontext of the user control" There are two different DataContexts - one for TorrentControl (where the MListItem is created) and another for the MemberListItem- it's own ViewModel. Should I try to put a DP in the TorrentControlViewModel and use that ViewModel for the MemberList VM?

Comment: Can you post the XAML for the user control "MemberListItem" - It is impossible for one object to have two data contexts.  You could specify a relative binding to an ancestor datacontext, but a control cannot have multiple data contexts.  The datacontext of the MemberListItem control, is one object in the "DiscFiles" collection (whatever that object type is)

Comment: You need to change the Text="{Binding ThisDoesntWorkYet}" in your user control from "ThisDoesntWorkYet" to whatever property you are trying to bind on the specific item of "DiscFiles".  So for example, if DiscFiles was a List of type "DiscFile", and each "DiscFile" had the property string "Name", you would set the textbox Text binding to Text="{Binding Name}" in your user control

Comment: DiscFile is just a type ObserableC<string>. Changed the UC DataContext to the other ViewModel. The image loads fine...Problem is setting the UC DataContext - the ViewModel has a couple of params that don't exist yet.